# Panel layout to uniformly squeeze items to fit

Tags: wpf, layout, stackpanel

I'm looking for a WPF layout that works like a horizontal stack panel, such that items choose their own ideal width when there is enough space for them to fit, but additionally squashes items evenly when they don't fit in the available panel space.

I can get close to what I want with this:

```
    <Grid Width="400" Height="80">
        <UniformGrid Rows="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Button Content="Long Button" />
            <Button Content="Very Long Button" />
            <Button Content="Button" />
            <Button Content="Button" />
            <Button Content="Button" />
        </UniformGrid>
    </Grid>
```

The problem here being the `UniformGrid` keeps all of the buttons the same width.

If I replace the `UniformGrid` with a `StackPanel`, then the items size correctly, but when they extend beyond the maximum size the `StackPanel` can grow to (thanks to its fixed size parent), they are clipped out, instead of being forced into the smaller area.

So, is there a way I can get the behavior I want with the out-of-the box panels?

Comment: If you want dynamic, no i don't know of a way of doing this. We wrote a custom panel to do something like this for dynamic content in an items control. If you don't need that, Rui Gaspars Answer is propably the best, but i would set the columndefinitions width always to *(star)

Comment: I'm having a try at creating a custom panel. It's seems easier than I thought it would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, is there a way I can get the behavior I want with the out-of-the box panels?

No, if you look at [all the existing panels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152.aspx#Panels_derived_elements) you will see there is not one which fits the requirements, implement your own.

Comment: It's exactly what I did. And it actually only took a few minutes to reproduce the exact behavior I wanted. Even though it's not the answer I wanted, you win.

Answer (score 0):

If the size of buttons is static, you can use this:

```
<Grid Width="400" Height="80">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Column="0" Content="Long Button" />
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Very Long Button" />
    <Button Grid.Column="2" Content="Button" />
    <Button Grid.Column="3" Content="Button" />
    <Button Grid.Column="4" Content="Button" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the content of the panel won't be static, so we can't know the ideal column widths beforehand.